# Issues on designing SQL users table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm creating a database that has a `users` table, but there are three types of users (admin, teachers and students) and some types has its own properties. Here are my solutions:

1 - Three different tables:

```
table_admin    
  id
  name
  email
  password

table_teachers
  id
  name
  email
  password
  teacher_only_a
  teacher_only_b

table_students 
  id
  name
  email
  password
  student_only_a
  student_only_b
```

2 - One table, allowing NULL values:

```
table_users
  id
  name
  email
  password
  teacher_only_a (null on admin and student)
  teacher_only_b (null on admin and student)
  student_only_a (null on admin and teacher)
  student_only_b (null on admin and teacher)
```

3 - Related tables:

```
table_users
  id
  name
  email
  password
  teacher_id (null on admin and student)
  student_id (null on admin and teacher)

table_teachers
  id
  teacher_only_a
  teacher_only_b

table_students 
  id
  student_only_a
  student_only_b
```

Which are the best design option? Is there another solution?

Comment: What is the relation of `admin` to everyone else?

Comment: `admin` doesn't have any additional property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not

```
table_users
  id
  name
  email
  password
  is_admin

table_teachers
  user_id
  teacher_only_a
  teacher_only_b

table_students 
  user_id
  student_only_a
  student_only_b
```

That would abstract out the user information so there isn't any redundancy.

Comment: Good one JJ32! I'd add a `type` field (just like `is_admin`) to build correctly join tables. I was using my third solution, but I couldn't use foreign key on that pattern. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I would opt for having two tables, one called `user` which will store user name, role, and other metadata, and a second table called `user_relation` which will store relationships between users.

**user**

```
id
name
email
password
role (admin, teacher, or student)
```

**user_relation**

```
id1
id2
```

I am making two assumptions here in my design.  The first is that a user's role will only be `admin`, `teacher`, or `student`.  If a user can be more than one role then you will need to create a new table `user_role` which stores this information.  The second assumption is that it will be clear what the nature of a relationship is merely by the types of users.  For example, if a record from `user_relation` contains a student and a teacher, then it will be implicitly assumed that the student belongs to that teacher's class.  Similarly, if a teacher and an admin have an entry, it will be assumed that the latter manages the former.  However, you could easily add a column for relation type if you wanted to make it more flexible and, for example, allow an admin to also be a student.

Answer (score 0):

Since users have dynamic varying attributes its is better to make a mapping attribute and just retrieve them separately, taking into consideration that they have the same data type. What is the value for teacher_only_a and student_only_a, what type of data is stored here?

```
table_user
  id
  name
  email
  password
  type // T:Teacher S:Student

table_user_attributes
  user_id
  attribute_name
  attribute_value
```

Comment: It could be string, number, date ... and sometimes NOT NULL